# (Excel-VBA) Specific data import (on the background) in the active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Would you please help me (total beginner) to prepare a VBA macro that would open a sheet on the background and import specific selection as shown below:

Let's say we have downloaded wordcount analysis (xlsx) like [this](https://moravia.sharefile.com/d-sad96362161c432fa) downloaded from a CAT tool for testing.

Now I would need to add a macro to my main sheet that would read lines starting (Column A) with "All". If "All" then I'd need to record columns of that line (specficilly Columns A - O) in array / hashtable?.

Please take a look at [this image](http://postimg.org/image/yx788qc9j/) that summs it all (better than explaining it for me :-)

Let me know in case you need to know more details.

All tips / suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @farb - you don't need VBA, you need to use a Pivot Table. Everything you are looking for is there with a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (I'm a beginner too) would be to use the Macro Recorder. Great tool to learn ([example](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)).

1. start recording
2. filter for 'ALL'
3. copy/past the Cells
4. stop Recording

Then have a look at the recorded code and adjust it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data and the final layout you are looking for, using a Pivot Table would provide you with all of the flexibility you need.

You can:

- filter which data to display
- generate calculated values based on data in other columns
- choose what order your columns are displayed
- dynamically change the layout if you decide you want a different view

From your data, I was able to generate the following Pivot Table in about 15 minutes.

[image]

There are several good, simple tutorials on building Pivot Tables. A Google search will turn up plenty.

Things you will need to learn about for your particular problem:

- Classic display (I used the classic display to get this particular layout)
- Calculated Fields (many of the columns in the pivot table are calculated based on your spec). There is a maximum string length of 255 characters for a field calculation, so you may need to rename some of the columns in the original data set.
- Of course, basics of Pivot Tables
- Loading new data and updating your pivot table

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however pivot table does not suitable for my kind of problem. To explain it further: We are using workbook1 as a tracking sheets for all projects containing several hundreds of lines. Each line is for one language. When new project comes e.g. for three languages then we just create another three lines with all the info. Problem is that allways have to download a XLSX analysis from external tool and convert these values to our workbook. It would be handy to just select that xlsx analysis via macro and import it automatically. I can share the TS with you for ref.